# Сортировка многомерного массива по вложенному элементу

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Есть вот такой массив

```
$inventory['status'] = 'success';
$inventory['weapons'][$i]['id'] = $itemID;
$inventory['weapons'][$i]['name'] = $name;
$inventory['weapons'][$i]['title'] = $market_name;
$inventory['weapons'][$i]['quality'] = $quality;
$inventory['weapons'][$i]['price'] = ($price >= 10)? round($price - ($price * 0.1), 0) : round($price - 2, 0);
```

Мне нужно его отсортировать по убыванию `price`.

Пробовал использовать sort, usort, но как я понял Они сортируют только массивы типа [1,3,2];

Желательно пример кода.

Comment: Отсортировать по убыванию какого элемента?

Comment: Price, забыл написать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией `uasort()`, передав ей в качестве второго параметра анонимную функцию, задающую логику сортировки сложного составного элемента массива (по элементу `price`)

```
<?php
$inventory['weapons'][0]['price'] = 10;
$inventory['weapons'][1]['price'] = 20;

uasort($inventory['weapons'], function($a, $b) {
  if ($a['price'] == $b['price']) return 0;
  return ($a['price'] > $b['price']) ? -1 : 1;
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r($inventory);
```